# How to convert drop down choice column to text field in Django forms

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make patient registration form in my project where Django automatically gives drop down choice list for the foreign key columns. How do I make that column into a text field as I need user to enter patient id instead of choosing from the long drop down list. I tried something but it didn't work for me. Please help if possible.

```
from django import forms
from HMSapp.models import Registration
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Pid=forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model=Registration
        fields='__all__'  
    def clean_Pid(self):
        patient_id=self.cleaned_data['Pid'] 
        try:
            Pid=Registration.objects.get(id=patient_id)
            return Pid
        except:
            raise ValidationError('Patient id does not exist')
```

Answer (score 0):

## === models.py ===

```
class CategoryModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ProductModel(models.Model):
    cate = models.ForeignKey(CategoryModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## === form.py =====

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cate = forms.CharField(widget=(forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter category id'})))
    class Meta:
        model = ProductModel
        fields = ('name', )
        exclude = ["cate"]

        widgets = {

            'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Product Name'})
        }
```

### === html code ===

```
<form action="" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          
          <p>{{form.name.label}}:{{form.name}}</p>
          <p>{{form.cate.label}}:{{form.cate}}</p>
               
          <p><button type="submit">Add</button></p>
          
     </form>
```

### === output ====

[image]

Comment: also check this link 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73689520/how-to-create-a-charfield-with-suggestions-in-django-forms/73690232#73690232

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: you want charfield instead of foreign key drop down ???

Comment: yes yes that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: answer updated plz check it